# How to load a csv file without knowing the number of columns beforehand

Tags: arrays, csv, d3.js

Here is what I try to do:
I want to visualize all permutations of people having certain diseases with bar charts.
E.g. I have a frequency count of people having certain diseases for all combinations. Let's say if there are 3 diseases, I have the count for 7 groups of people. For 4 diseases, there are 15 possible groups of people and for n diseases there are 2^n-1 combinations.

A suitable csv file structure for this data is:

```
frequency,disease1,disease2,disease3,disease4
40,1,0,0,0
36,1,0,1,0
25,0,1,0,0
37,0,0,0,1
20,0,0,1,1
5,1,1,1,1
```

Row 2 meaning 40 people having just disease1 but no other. Row 3 meaning 36 people have disease1 and disease3.

Well, after looking through the examples of how to read from a csv file, I didn't find an answer for this file structure (for which I don't know how many columns are contained beforehand).

My intial bar chart for this example should show 4 bars, one for each disease - with the height being all counts where this disease occured (has a value 1). 
Then after a bar is selected, I plan to update the remaining bars for this subset (not implemented yet -  but the data structure should efficiently support it).

Can some give me a hint how to load the initial data structure (from the unknown number of attributes)?

I add my current version below where I realize on line 89

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x("disease1"); })
```

that I cannot access the column names dynamically. My current thought is best to create an array of arrays for the values and a separate array for the attribute names. But I haven't figured it out how since filling up Arrays from properties collides with the arbitrary order in which the 'for ...in' loop iterates. 
An alternative where each value is represented by

```
{key: 'column name 1'; value: value}
```

seems prohibitiv due to the amount of redundancy.

My current version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var permutations;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    // .ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("diseases.csv", type, function(error, data) {
      permutations = data;
      var products = d3.keys(permutations[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key != "frequency";});

  // debugger;
  x.domain(products);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x("disease1"); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

});

function type(d) {
    for (var perm in d) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(d, perm)) {
            console.log("before: " + d[perm]);
            d[perm] = +d[perm];
            console.log("after: "+ d[perm]);
        }
    }    
    // d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to sum the frequencies (first column) for each disease, and create a bar chart using those frequencies. You can change how you process the data loaded from the CSV file:

```
d3.csv("diseases.csv", type, function(error, permutations) {
    var diseases = d3.keys(permutations[0]).filter(function(key) { return key != "frequency";}),
        data = diseases.map(function(d){ return {disease: d, frequency: 0}});
    permutations.forEach(function(row){
        diseases.forEach(function(d, i){
            if (row[d] === 1){
                data[i].frequency += row["frequency"];
            }
        })
    })
```

to store your `data` in an array that looks like this:

```
[{"disease":"disease1","frequency":81},{"disease":"disease2","frequency":30},
 {"disease":"disease3","frequency":61},{"disease":"disease4","frequency":62}]
```

Then just modify the `x` domain:

```
x.domain(diseases);
```

and the `x` attribute when you draw your `<rect>`s to use the particular disease:

```
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.disease); })
```

Making these changes gives me the following bar chart:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good reply!! As I mentioned in my post, the data structure you propose seems inefficient since it's so redundant (storing column names repeatedly every row). It would greatly help me understanding the basics if you could clarify/comment on this: a) it's not possible to construct an array of array (with just values - and an array with column names) from the properties since iteration over them comes with an arbitrary order so I cannot fill the array correctly or b) your approach has some benefits which I don't understand. Any elaboration would be very helpful!

Comment: @user3902128: ah I didn't understand from your post that you meant this data structure. I don't think it is particularly inefficient for two reasons 1) Your dataset is quite small (though perhaps this isn't the full dataset. 2) Compared to the alternative data structure you describe in (a), the dataset used here is only larger by a constant factor.

Comment: Thanks!! Though I plan to load data with a larger number of diseases (up to 18) where I will have 2^18 rows, you are right to just have an increase by a constant factor. I will try that! Thanks so much !!!

Comment: Glad to help, good luck! Also, if you my answer solved your problem, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).