# for...in statement - what does arbitrary order mean

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-5

I have a very basic ECMAScript question which I am not sure about reading the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in 
or questions.

I want to iterate over an object e.g. to construct an array. See also my question:
[How to load a csv file without knowing the number of columns beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912598/how-to-load-a-csv-file-without-knowing-the-number-of-columns-beforehand)

If I read a csv file with d3.js, I obtain an array of objects. I want to build an array of array from it, so I use a for (key in obj) statement. Do I have to make property checks for every object to ensure the right order (one interpretation of arbitrary order) or can I assume the properties will be picked up in the same order (second interpretation: just the order is arbitrary - but stable). It seems like many examples assume the latter interpretation.
Can someone please clarify ?

Comment: JavaScript object properties are never guaranteed to be in any particular order. They might be, but it's not guaranteed. Use a linear array if you need ordered elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not expect `for..in` statements to iterate over your object properties in any particular order even across iterations of objects with the same attributes. There are different approaches you can take to ensure proper order, here is the one I use regularly:

```
// this is the order I want the values in
var order       = ['id', 'first', 'last'];
var collection  = [{ first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe', id: 1}, {last: 'Smith', id: 2, first: 'John'}];
var outputArray = [];

collection.forEach(function(row){
  var tmpRow = [];
  for(var attr in row){
    // get the target index of the current attribute
    var index = order.indexOf(attr);
    // insert into desired position
    tmpRow[index] = row[attr];
  }
  outputArray.push(tmpRow);
})

console.log(outputArray)
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Terrific. Great answer with example which confirms my thoughts. Thanks a lot, I will use that approach.